# update role once coin threshold is reached (economy system)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm wondering how to make my discord bot update someone's role once they collect 500 coins. They only need to reach the target no. once to receive the role and they shouldn't lose it even if their coins dips below 500 again. This is an attempt I made in my guild events folder but obviously it just sends the message every time the user enters a command because their coins are over 500. Any advice is appreciated.

```
module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = '!';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    let profileData;
    try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if(!profileData){
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                userID: message.author.id, 
                serverID: message.guild.id, 
                coins: 0,
            });
            profile.save();
        }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`You have to wait ${time_left.toFixed(0)} seconds before you can perform ${command.name} again.`);
        }
    }

    const user = message.author || message.author;
    const userData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: user.id });
    if(userData.coins >= 500){
        message.member.roles.remove("oldroleid");
        message.member.roles.add('newroleid');
        message.channel.send('Congratulations, you have reached the second level.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With my currect skill, You can do this if you want to check the message author profile and add a roles to it whenever they have some certain value automatically.

**Updating when anybody sent a message**

The simple way to do this is check the message author user profile every `client.on('message')` event triggered. Its quite simple to do this. Just move your profile update code to your `on('message')` event.

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {

    const userData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    if (userData.coins >= 500){
        message.member.roles.remove("oldroleid");
        message.member.roles.add('newroleid');
        message.channel.send('Congratulations, you have reached the second level.');
    }

    // rest of your code

})
```

So they don't need to run some specific commands.

Also put this code on the top of your `client.on('message')` code. So it will not get any filter that you just set. Like
`if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;`

If you use Event Handler. You can just put the code in below the `module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {` thingy.

And it should works as normal, tell me if its not.